# how to install sftp on windows 2008 r2 and transfer file through c#

Tags: c#, sftp, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to create a Proof of concept where i need to install SFTP on windows server 2008 R2 and then i need to write a program in C# to transfer file to that SFTP server

i dont know anything abut installing SFTP server but on c# i have some know how to send file to SFTP server

I have tried to use FileZilla but i am not able to configure it properly.

Please recommend me some tutorial to install SFTP server on windows 2008 R2 and to send file through c# to that server

Comment: I recommend you http://www.vandyke.com/products/securefx/windows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try freeFTPd,  found here:

http://www.freesshd.com/

With FileZilla you cannot set up an SFTP server.

For sending the file using C#, as far as I know .NET does not have any libraries for connecting to an SFTP server. You should use a third party library.

Comment: For Sending in SFTP I strongly recommend [SSHNET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com)